# Try-Catch block getting length of string error

Tags: java, try-catch

I have everything working but I am having an issue with the JTextField. When the user  submits nothing, it should be returning `null` rather than `0`. So far it's returning 0, but I need it to return NULL. It's not reaching the Catch block at all even if I put `System.out.println("test");` it's not reaching there.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class stringlength implements ActionListener {

  public static JLabel outputLabel;
  public static JTextField inputField = new JTextField(20);

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    stringlength myWindow = new stringlength ();

  }

  public stringlength (){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("stringlength");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(500,100);
    //frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.add(panel);

    outputLabel = new JLabel("String length = ");
    JButton stringLengthButton = new JButton("Get String Length");
    stringLengthButton.addActionListener(this);


    panel.add(stringLengthButton);
    panel.add(outputLabel);
    panel.add(inputField);

  }


  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    try{
    String text = inputField.getText();
    System.out.println(text);
    outputLabel.setText("String length = " + text.length());
    }
    catch(NullPointerException e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();

    }
  }

}
```

Comment: No really, why are you catching a `NullPointerException`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

  try{
    String text = inputField.getText();
    System.out.println(text);
    outputLabel.setText("String length = " + text.length());
    if (text.length()==0)
      throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    catch(NullPointerException e1)
    {
      e1.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`getText()` will never return `null`.  If you want a `null` value, or an exception, you will have to detect a zero-length string and return `null` or throw the exception yourself.

[JavaDoc for getText()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText())

Answer (score 0):

Let me ask you... What if you can return null. Is your code supposed to give the user a second try at entering a string ?? if so then try

```
    try
        {
        firstTry = inputField.getText();
            if(firstTry.length() == 0)
                {
                    outputLabel.setText("String Length = "+secondTry.length());
                }
            else
                {
                outputLabel.setText("String length = "+firstTry.length());
                }
        }//end try
    catch(NullPointerException e1)
        {
            secondTry=JOptionPane.showInputDialog ( "empty try again" );
            outputLabel.setText("String Length = "+secondTry.length());
        }//end catch
```